# MVC2 routing problem on IIS 7.5 (on Cassini it works fine)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

I've published my MVC2 app on IIS 7.5 (.net 4 framework, integrated app pool).
And I have a routing problem, I've got 404.0 error message when I ask a controller's view.
The problem was not appeared in VS2010/Cassini environment (its working without problem). 
If I change the **controller name** and **action** in last parameter of the **routes.maproute** calling, it works fine.
How should I modify my routes? 
Thanks.

Here is my global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                         // Route name 
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",      // URL with parameters 
        new
        { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    ); 

}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: What did you change them to to get it working?

Comment: I just try it. The Home controller's Index view is working, but other views are not. Other views (ex. Customer/Index) is working when I modify global.asax.cs:     

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                         // Route name 
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",      // URL with parameters 
        new
        { controller = "Customer", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    ); 
What should I do to working other views? Thanks.

Comment: Does the app itself sit at the domain root?

Comment: Yes. Is it the problem? 
Thanks.